# Android ListView CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE will not set

Tags: java, android, listview, selector, drawerlayout

Here's an app that targets Android 4.1+.
I want an active state on the listview.  I am using code in other apps that I hae where this worked properly.  Not sure what the difference is here (except for API version is higher).

I have this Java:

```
    DrawerAdapter lAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(this, modeList);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(lAdapter);
    mDrawerList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(0, true);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos,
                long id) {

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(pos, true);
           }
```

**Drawer Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:cacheColorHint="#ececec"
        android:background="@drawable/tile_repeat"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/nav_selector"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Selector**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/nav_press" android:state_activated="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <!-- CHECKED -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/nav_active" android:state_activated="true" android:state_pressed="false" />

</selector>
```

**nav_active:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#cecece" />
</shape>
```

Am I missing a step?  the Press state works fine, just not the activated.

**Root view of `DrawerAdapter`  `row_drawer_layout.xml`**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMenuItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#005348"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**DrawerAdapter:**

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;

public DrawerAdapter(Context context, String[] sizeList) {
    super(context, 0, sizeList);
    this.context = context;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tv1;
    public TextView tv2;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_drawer_layout, null, true);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvMenuItem);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    String s = getItem(position);
    holder.tv1.setText(s);

    return rowView;

}
```

}

Comment: What is your root view of `DrawerAdapter.getView` method.

Comment: @blazsolar  I added the code above for that..,.

Answer (score 2):

Your root view of `ListView` item should implement `Checkable` interface. In your case that is `LinearLayout` witch does note implement `Checkable`. You should just use `CheckedTextView` in your layout.

It should look something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tvMenuItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#005348"
        android:background="@drawable/checkable_item"/>
```

If you want to have more complex layout inside your item you could extend one of android layouts and add `Checkable` interface to it. [Here](https://gist.github.com/blazsolar/9096254) is an example of `RelativeLayout``

To change background on checked item you should use `checked` state in selector:

```
checkable_item.xml
<selector>
    ...
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/some_drawable" />
    ...
</selector>
```

Comment: Well, I am not trying to change the `TextView` but the Background color of the row, so this wouldn't apply would it?

Comment: To change background on checked items you should just set `android:background` to `selector` that has `android:state_checked="true"` set to color you want.

Answer (score 0):

To fix, this is what I did:

I added `android:background="@drawable/nav_selector"`   to the root `LinearLayout` on `row_drawer_layout.xml`;  now the row stays active when user selects.

I thank @blazsolar for this help.  His second comment lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for responding so late but I had quite struggle about this. All you have to do is to add the property `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` to the `row_drawer_layout.xml` file.
Finally, it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMenuItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#005348"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the ***correct way*** doing this since it is using the `activatedBackgroundIndicator` defined by the style, which means that when you set the custom style it will affect all listviews (if not specified otherwise).